# clickedButtonAtIndex method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

when the user  click on a button on the `UIAlertView` the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method is supposed to be called, however, it doesn't :

in the `.h` i have called the `UIAlertView` protocol :

```
@interface RechercherViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>  {

//code
}
```

and in `.m` file i have this :

```
-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    //quand il y aura un échec lors de l'envoie de la requête

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TopStation"
                                                message :@"Your internet connexion is down"
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];

                       [alert show];
                       [alert release];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"buttonIndex 0");
    } else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"buttonIndex 1");
    }
}
```

nothing is shown in the log file, please help, thx in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delegate:nil` is the problem. Pass `self` as the delegate to `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `nil` as the delegate argument. Pass `self` instead.